# How can I make this responsive menu work on window resize for desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to add some classes to a WordPress menu in order for it to work on mobile. The only problem is the preventDefault, which disables the default click action for menu items with submenus and instead go to the next level, runs and when you're viewing the desktop site, top level menu items aren't clickable. How can I alter the code so on window resize, the javascript runs for mobile but on a larger window (e.g. larger than 768px), the code doesn't run and the preventDefault is ignored?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Adding 'has-submenu' class to first level for mobile
        $('.menu > ul > li > ul.sub-menu').closest('li').addClass('has-submenu');

        // JS media query for disabling and enabling top level click
        var $menu = $('#menu'),
        $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
        $menuTrigger = $('.has-submenu > a');

        $menulink.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $menulink.toggleClass('active');
            $menu.toggleClass('active');
        });

        $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle. Notice how on responsive, clicking a parent menu item expands the menu. This functions the way I'd like. However, when you blow it out to the larger desktop version, notice that the preventDefault is disallowing you to click a parent menu item. I'd like these to be clickable on the larger desktop version.

http://jsfiddle.net/2U8Md/

Comment: can you provide a little html and css. Or a jsfiddle. So we can help you quicker.

Comment: I can simply suggest something like (unformal code) `if(window.size > xxx){ e.preventDefault;// bahbahbah} else {...}` And you need to override `$menuTrigger.hover()` in the same way. So in one case, click event is kept, hover event in the other one.

Comment: Use `$(window).resize(callback)`. Check the window size in the callback and `on`/`off` click the menu accordingly

Comment: Hmmm, this still doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/2U8Md/1/

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/2U8Md/3/)?

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either.

Comment: tewathia, on your jsfiddle, the parent menu items still don't link on the > 600px wide desktop version. Also, upon multiple resizes, the mobile menu button stops functioning.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ZHx5b/

Comment: Please post it as an answer and I'll mark it.